# How to extract noun-based compound words from a sentence using Python?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I'm using `nltk` via the following code to extract nouns from a sentence:

```py
words = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
tags = nltk.pos_tag(words)
```

And then I choose the words tagged with the `NN` and `NNP` Part of Speech (PoS) tags. However, it only extracts single nouns like "book" and "table", yet ignores the pair of nouns like "basketball shoe". What should I do to expand the results to contain such compond noun pairs?

Comment: The keyword you're looking for is probably *multi-word expressions* (MWEs). Since you're using NLTK, does the [NLTK MWETokenizer](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tokenize/mwe.html) do what you want?

Comment: Hi fsimonjetz, I have read through the document, it requires me to pre-define the pair. However, I'm looking for something that's more general, that doesn't need to be defined in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just want to find [noun-noun compounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_(linguistics)#Noun%E2%80%93noun_compounds) (e.g. "book store") and not other combinations like `noun`-`verb` (e.g. "snow fall") or `adj`-`noun` (e.g. "hot dog"), the following solution will capture 2 or more consecutive occurrences of either the [NN](https://sites.google.com/site/partofspeechhelp/home#TOC-NN), [NNS](https://sites.google.com/site/partofspeechhelp/home#TOC-NNS), [NNP](https://sites.google.com/site/partofspeechhelp/home#TOC-NNP) or [NNPS](https://sites.google.com/site/partofspeechhelp/home#TOC-NNPS) Part of Speech (PoS) tags.

### Example

Using the `NLTK RegExpParser` with the custom grammar rule defined in the solution below, three compound nouns ("basketball shoe", "book store" and "peanut butter") are extracted from the following sentence:

> John lost his basketball shoe in the book store while eating peanut butter

[image: Parse tree detection of consecutive nouns]

### Solution

```py
from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag, RegexpParser

text = "John lost his basketball shoe in the book store while eating peanut butter"
tokenized = word_tokenize(text)  # Tokenize text
tagged = pos_tag(tokenized)  # Tag tokenized text with PoS tags

# Create custom grammar rule to find consecutive occurrences of nouns
my_grammar = r"""
CONSECUTIVE_NOUNS: {<N.*><N.*>+}"""


# Function to create parse tree using custom grammar rules and PoS tagged text
def get_parse_tree(grammar, pos_tagged_text):
    cp = RegexpParser(grammar)
    parse_tree = cp.parse(pos_tagged_text)
    # parse_tree.draw()  # Visualise parse tree
    return parse_tree


# Function to get labels from custom grammar:
# takes line separated NLTK regexp grammar rules
def get_labels_from_grammar(grammar):
    labels = []
    for line in grammar.splitlines()[1:]:
        labels.append(line.split(":")[0])
    return labels


# Function takes parse tree & list of NLTK custom grammar labels as input
# Returns phrases which match
def get_phrases_using_custom_labels(parse_tree, custom_labels_to_get):
    matching_phrases = []
    for node in parse_tree.subtrees(filter=lambda x: any(x.label() == custom_l for custom_l in custom_labels_to_get)):
        # Get phrases only, drop PoS tags
        matching_phrases.append([leaf[0] for leaf in node.leaves()])
    return matching_phrases


text_parse_tree = get_parse_tree(my_grammar, tagged)
my_labels = get_labels_from_grammar(my_grammar)
phrases = get_phrases_using_custom_labels(text_parse_tree, my_labels)

for phrase in phrases:
    print(phrase)
```

### Output

```
['basketball', 'shoe']
['book', 'store']
['peanut', 'butter']
```